# Where is gambas3 installed?

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu, paths, location, gambas3

I want to install the [xt7-player-mpv video player](https://github.com/kokoko3k/xt7-player-mpv/), which was recently updated.

It is not available for Ubuntu as deb and compiling it required Gambas3. That is available and can be installed with

```
sudo apt install gambas3
[sudo] password for cip: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  debugedit gambas3-dev gambas3-examples gambas3-gb-args gambas3-gb-cairo gambas3-gb-chart gambas3-gb-clipper gambas3-gb-complex gambas3-gb-compress
  gambas3-gb-compress-bzlib2 gambas3-gb-compress-zlib gambas3-gb-crypt gambas3-gb-data gambas3-gb-db gambas3-gb-db-form gambas3-gb-db-mysql
  gambas3-gb-db-odbc gambas3-gb-db-postgresql gambas3-gb-db-sqlite3 gambas3-gb-dbus gambas3-gb-dbus-trayicon gambas3-gb-desktop
  gambas3-gb-desktop-x11 gambas3-gb-eval-highlight gambas3-gb-form gambas3-gb-form-dialog gambas3-gb-form-editor gambas3-gb-form-mdi
  gambas3-gb-form-stock gambas3-gb-form-terminal gambas3-gb-gmp gambas3-gb-gsl gambas3-gb-gui gambas3-gb-httpd gambas3-gb-image-effect
  gambas3-gb-image-imlib gambas3-gb-image-io gambas3-gb-inotify gambas3-gb-jit gambas3-gb-logging gambas3-gb-map gambas3-gb-markdown
  gambas3-gb-media gambas3-gb-media-form gambas3-gb-memcached gambas3-gb-mime gambas3-gb-mysql gambas3-gb-ncurses gambas3-gb-net gambas3-gb-net-curl
  gambas3-gb-net-pop3 gambas3-gb-net-smtp gambas3-gb-openal gambas3-gb-opengl gambas3-gb-opengl-glsl gambas3-gb-opengl-glu gambas3-gb-opengl-sge
  gambas3-gb-openssl gambas3-gb-pcre gambas3-gb-pdf gambas3-gb-qt5-ext gambas3-gb-qt5-opengl gambas3-gb-qt5-webkit gambas3-gb-report2
  gambas3-gb-scanner gambas3-gb-sdl2 gambas3-gb-sdl2-audio gambas3-gb-settings gambas3-gb-signal gambas3-gb-term gambas3-gb-term-form
  gambas3-gb-util gambas3-gb-util-web gambas3-gb-vb gambas3-gb-web gambas3-gb-web-feed gambas3-gb-web-form gambas3-gb-xml gambas3-gb-xml-html
  gambas3-gb-xml-rpc gambas3-gb-xml-xslt gambas3-ide gambas3-script libalure1 libdumb1 libglew2.1 libgmime-3.0-0 libgsl23 libgslcblas0 libimlib2
  libodbc1 libpq5 librpm8 librpmbuild8 librpmio8 librpmsign8 libsdl2-image-2.0-0 libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0 libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0 rpm rpm-common rpm2cpio
```

The compiling instructions are:

```
After you installed gambas 3, just checkout and compile xt7 that way:

# git clone https://github.com/kokoko3k/xt7-player-mpv.git
# cd xt7-player-mpv/
# /path/to/gambas/binaries/gbc3 -e -a -g -t -p -m
# /path/to/gambas/binaries/gba3
# ./xt7-player-mpv.gambas
```

But I don't seem to find that path to `/gambas/binaries`.

Using `sudo find / -type d -name "gambas" 2>/dev/null` nothing is found.

This is in Kubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=bin%2Fgambas3) you need to install `gambas3-ide` to have `/usr/bin/gambas3` in installed to the system.
Full set of the packages is below:

```
sudo apt-get install gambas3 gambas3-ide gambas3-dev gambas3-gb-libxml
```

Also you can simply omit `/path/to/gambas/binaries/` as all the needed Gambas binaries [are](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=focal&section=all&arch=any&keywords=bin%2Fgbc3&searchon=contents) [installed](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=focal&section=all&arch=any&keywords=bin%2Fgba3&searchon=contents) to `/usr/bin/` which is in `$PATH` variable:

```
git clone https://github.com/kokoko3k/xt7-player-mpv.git
cd xt7-player-mpv/
gbc3 -e -a -g -t -p -m
gba3
./xt7-player-mpv.gambas
```

Comment: As seen in the `apt install` info posted in question `gambas3-ide` was installed with `gambas3` (only `gambas3-gb-libxml` was not, and it was the only one installed after the `apt-get install` as said in the answer). But still no gambas directory in /usr/bin/ etc. `gbc3 -e -a -g -t -p -m` gives `gbc3: warning: unable to compile translation file with 'msgfmt': de.po OK`

Comment: @cipricus since you are getting a warning message *from `gbc3`*, it doesn't seem to be the location of gambas binaries that is the problem here. It looks like it may be an issue with localization.

Comment: @steeldriver - does that mean that gambas3 is well in place and found by that `gbc3` command but that some other dependency is needed for compiling xt7?

Comment: I have successfully compiled and run xt7 while using above commands. You can ignore message about *de.po*.

Comment: `I have successfully compiled and run xt7 while using above commands.` - That confirms your answer. (But I'm on a new system now and I hesitate to use `sudo apt-get install gambas3 gambas3-ide gambas3-dev gambas3-gb-libxml` when I see it triggers 163 more dependencies. It's too much to ask for one player.)